# CoreAnimation layer delegate + implicit animation differences in iPhone 4S / 4

Tags: ios, core-animation

I understand from a few posts on SO that in order for CoreAnimation-based *implicit animations* to work on iPhone, one has to set the delegate of the layer being animated to the view controller doing the animation. What tripped me up was this:

- I started by testing on an iPhone 4S, where I forgot to do the set delegate step. The animations showed up fine.
- I then tested on an iPhone 4, and couldn't for the life of me figure out why the animations weren't showing up. Of course, they worked once I added the set delegate step... but why?

Does anyone know why this is the case? Is it an issue of how the threads are being run on a 4S? I'm fairly new to CoreAnimation and the internal workings of iOS processes.

Edit for more info: both devices are on the same iOS version, 5.0.

Comment: Are versions of iOS installed on devices are the same?